# apply standard SF background to a VF page?

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have a vf page that just contains a custom button. That VF page is embedded in a std page layout. The way this is rendering now, is that I have a white background, like the screen shot below. How do I fix this?

[image]

```
 <apex:page standardController="Opportunity" standardStylesheets="true"   extensions="OpportunityController" >
  <apex:form >
   <center>
    <base target="_parent" />
    <apex:commandButton action="{!redirect}"  value="Change Record Type" rendered="{!render}"/>
    </center>
     </apex:form>
   </apex:page>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly it looks like your using the old user interface theme of Salesforce? Since the latest does have a white background. You can chance this via Setup > User Interface and ticking the 'Enable New User Interface Theme'. This will switch the background for standard layouts to white and match your VF page.

[image]

If you for some reason do not want to make this change....

I got something close using standard VF component apex:pageBlock around your button, which matches the background colour, but also rendered an orange header bar .

```
<apex:pageBlock> your button here </apex:pageBlock>
```

[image]

I could not seem to find a way using a standard VF component container to force the CSS output to match the native UI, so while its a bit of hack (aka will not track the theme changes of Salesforce) you can just do this and it works fine.

```
<body style="background:#f3f3ec" > your page code here </body>
```

[image]

Other Salesforce CSS hackers may come up with a better, less hacky version. However the two safest options (in terms of your page tracking future changes) are to use one of the standard components like pageBlock above to get a bit closer to the standard sections colours (in this case you won't need a section on your layout as the page will render it) or easiest option if your org admin is happy with it, is to simply switch on the latest Salesforce Theme.

Comment: Thanks Andrew. Modifying the UI, is something that will be done in coming months, as we activate chatter. As of now, this is the way that business wants things.  The 'hack' gets me where i need to be. I was looking for something that matched the native automatically, but it's not a deal breaker.